# How to get query result from large no. of rows using linq and database is sql server, search field is an image

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I've to get a row from Sql Server database where search field is an image and there are large no. of rows. Actually I've to get row using linq from Sql Server matching finger print from large no. rows. I want the search speed should be as fast as possible. Please suggest how I'll modify my code following or something new or something have to do in Sql Server:-

```
       public async Task<Register> GetRegister(Byte[] _fingerPrint1)
       {
            dc = new Domain.HMEntities();
            Register _Register = new Domain.PatientRegister();

            _Register = dc.PatientRegisters.Where(l => l.Image1 ==  _fingerPrint1).FirstOrDefault();

            dc.Dispose();
            return _Register;
        }///
```

Comment: Will your database contains perfect fit for image you search ? Or it contain only somewhat similar image and you need to check for degree of similiarty ?

Comment: Look my image is a fingerprint and successfully saved in a varbinary(MAX) field . I'm also able to retrieve the row and the fingerprint, searching with another filed like, username. But I want retrieve the row matching the fingerprint.

Comment: It seems unorthodox to search by varbinary(MAX) however since this is a hard constraint I can really only offer two pieces of advice.

1. Hash your images in the database and store that value, then search by the hashed value of the image that you are seeking to match.

2. Index your database on the hashed value.